# CSS bottom:0 not working when creating timeline?

Tags: html, css

This is the desired timeline I want to create https://codepen.io/paulhbarker/pen/apvGdv.

Let me explain my way of approach. I am creating a "ul" and every time line is inside the "li" of that unordered list with the class name "card". Here, "li" is set to position relative and "card" is set to position absolute. Then I select every odd "li" and transform the "card" to left and I transform the "card" to right in case of even "li". Till here it is working as I am expecting.

I am using ":after" pseudo selector in li and adding a circular pin point at the "bottom:0" position. I am adding certain width, bg color and padding to li to create a line. The thing is I want my card to appear in the position of circular pin point which is "bottom:0" of the ":after" pseudo selector of "li". But the cards are above the pinpoint.

[image]

HTML:

```
 <section id="timeline">
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-heading color--blue">
                            <div class="card-number">
                                <span>01</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="heading-description">
                                <h2><span class="small">SUBTITLE</span> <br />TECHNOLOGY</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.
                            </p>
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
                        </div>
                   </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-heading color--blue">
                         <div class="card-number">
                             <span>01</span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="heading-description">
                             <h2><span class="small">SUBTITLE</span> <br />TECHNOLOGY</h2>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <p class="card-text">
                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.
                         </p>
                         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
                     </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-heading color--blue">
                         <div class="card-number">
                             <span>01</span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="heading-description">
                             <h2><span class="small">SUBTITLE</span> <br />TECHNOLOGY</h2>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <p class="card-text">
                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.
                         </p>
                         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
                     </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-heading color--blue">
                         <div class="card-number">
                             <span>01</span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="heading-description">
                             <h2><span class="small">SUBTITLE</span> <br />TECHNOLOGY</h2>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <p class="card-text">
                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.
                         </p>
                         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
                     </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-heading color--blue">
                         <div class="card-number">
                             <span>01</span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="heading-description">
                             <h2><span class="small">SUBTITLE</span> <br />TECHNOLOGY</h2>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <p class="card-text">
                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.
                         </p>
                         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
                     </div>
                </div>
            </li>
           </ul>
       </section>
```

CSS:

```
#timeline{
    margin-top:300px;
}
body{
    background-color: rgb(223, 219, 219);
}

#timeline ul li{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 6px;
    /* padding-top: different for even and off */
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}

#timeline ul li:after{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom:0;
    background: inherit;
    transform: translateX(-40%);
}

.card img{
    width: 100%;
}
.card{
    position: absolute;
    width:370px;
    height:380px;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Roboto";
}

.card .card-heading{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    padding:15px 0px 15px 20px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

.card .card-heading .card-number{
    background-color: #3A99C2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:55px;
    height:50px;
    color:white;
    font-size:35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 10px;
}

/* Timeline setting for odd element */

#timeline li:nth-child(odd) .card{
    transform: translateX(-120%);
}

#timeline li:nth-child(odd){
    padding-top: 400px;
}

#timeline li:first-child{
    padding-top: 100px;
}
#timeline li:nth-child(odd) .card .card-heading:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    right:-3%;
    top:34%;
    border-left:14px solid transparent;
    border-left-color:inherit;
    border-top:14px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:14px solid transparent;
}   


/* Timeline even */
#timeline li:nth-child(even) .card .card-heading:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left:-3%;
    top:34%;
    border-right:14px solid transparent;
    border-right-color:inherit;
    border-top:14px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:14px solid transparent;
}   
#timeline li:nth-child(even) .card{
    transform: translateX(20%);
}
#timeline li:nth-child(even){
    padding-top: 100px;
}




.card .card-heading .heading-description{
    color:white;
    display: inline;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: -20px 0px 0px 10px;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.card .card-body{
    padding:0px 15px 15px 15px;
}
.card .small{
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.color--blue{
    background-color: #46B8E9;
    border-color:#46B8E9;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you needed it to be a :before instead of an :after and also removed some margin on the li.  Check out how i updated it

```css
#timeline{
    margin-top:300px;
}
body{
    background-color: rgb(223, 219, 219);
}

#timeline ul li{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 6px;
    /* padding-top: different for even and off */
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}

#timeline ul li:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background: inherit;
    transform: translateX(-40%);
}

.card img{
    width: 100%;
}
.card{
   
    width:370px;
    height:380px;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Roboto";
}

.card .card-heading{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    padding:15px 0px 15px 20px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

.card .card-heading .card-number{
    background-color: #3A99C2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:55px;
    height:50px;
    color:white;
    font-size:35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 10px;
}

/* Timeline setting for odd element */

#timeline li:nth-child(odd) .card{
    transform: translateX(-120%);
}

#timeline li:nth-child(odd){
    padding-top: 100px;
}

#timeline li:first-child{
    padding-top: 0px;
}
#timeline li:nth-child(odd) .card .card-heading:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    right:-3%;
    top:34%;
    border-left:14px solid transparent;
    border-left-color:inherit;
    border-top:14px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:14px solid transparent;
}   


/* Timeline even */
#timeline li:nth-child(even) .card .card-heading:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left:-3%;
    top:34%;
    border-right:14px solid transparent;
    border-right-color:inherit;
    border-top:14px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:14px solid transparent;
}   
#timeline li:nth-child(even) .card{
    transform: translateX(20%);
}
#timeline li:nth-child(even){
    padding-top: 100px;
}




.card .card-heading .heading-description{
    color:white;
    display: inline;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: -20px 0px 0px 10px;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.card .card-body{
    padding:0px 15px 15px 15px;
}
.card .small{
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.color--blue{
    background-color: #46B8E9;
    border-color:#46B8E9;
}
```

```html
    <section id="timeline">
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-heading color--blue">
                            <div class="card-number">
                                <span>01</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="heading-description">
                                <h2><span class="small">SUBTITLE</span> <br />TECHNOLOGY</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.
                            </p>
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
                        </div>
                   </div>
               </li>
               <li>
                <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-heading color--blue">
                         <div class="card-number">
                             <span>01</span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="heading-description">
                             <h2><span class="small">SUBTITLE</span> <br />TECHNOLOGY</h2>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <p class="card-text">
                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.
                         </p>
                         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
                     </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-heading color--blue">
                         <div class="card-number">
                             <span>01</span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="heading-description">
                             <h2><span class="small">SUBTITLE</span> <br />TECHNOLOGY</h2>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <p class="card-text">
                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.
                         </p>
                         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
                     </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-heading color--blue">
                         <div class="card-number">
                             <span>01</span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="heading-description">
                             <h2><span class="small">SUBTITLE</span> <br />TECHNOLOGY</h2>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <p class="card-text">
                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.
                         </p>
                         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
                     </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-heading color--blue">
                         <div class="card-number">
                             <span>01</span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="heading-description">
                             <h2><span class="small">SUBTITLE</span> <br />TECHNOLOGY</h2>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <p class="card-text">
                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta reiciendis deserunt doloribus consequatur, laudantium odio dolorum laboriosam.
                         </p>
                         <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x500" alt="Graphic">
                     </div>
                </div>
            </li>
           </ul>
       </section>
```

Comment: Well It is not quite what I want. Your solution is just keeping every element equally apart from each other. Check the code pen once, there is a little difference between 1st and 2nd element but there is huge difference between 1st and 3rd if you can understand what am I saying.

Comment: Simple in the code pen see the position of 1st and 2nd circular pin, they are quite near but the third is quite far. Similarly , 3rd and 4th are near to each other while the 5th is far. I want to mimic that that's why I set card to absolute. and odd and even li have different margin.